# What data types can be passed to redux-thunk actions?

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

**Problem overview**

I am using redux-form, and it wraps my compoent, and provides as a property *change()* which is a bound function for changing the form. I wanted to invoke this in an actionCreator.

**Issue**

I thought I could just pass it to my actionCreator thunk, but it seems that the value is stripped on dispatch of the action.

**Details**

So what I tried instead of sending the bound action *change* I tried instead to send a pointer to one of my other actionCreators called act.setFMEPATH, but that is also not working.

In the first picture below I show the state of the variables in before the dispatach to the redux-action occurs. As you can see from the watch, act.setFMEPath clearly is defined.

In the second picture you see the state of the action when it is entered. defaultPath is define (it is scoped to a closure on the stack), but the storeAct.

In my code, I am hard coding the STORE.dispatch(Act.setFMEPath(filePath[0]) since the paramater storeAct is not visible, But what I want it STORE.dispatch(storeAct(filePath[0])

Should I be binding the context of the first parameter to the dispatch() and turning storeAct() into a bound function (but note it is an arrow function, so that is not going to work).

**State before call:**

[image]

**State entry of pickFile action creator**

[image]

Comment: I don't think you've provided enough to answer your question. pickFolder is a function, so you can pass to it whatever you could normally pass. If it's undefined in pickFolder that's because it was undefined in the caller.

Comment: @Radio- you are correct. I will add more detail tomorrow inline to the main comment. But basically, the debugger shows that Act.setSourcePath is bound to a function when dispatch is called in the caller. But when I enter the receiver *(the PickFolder action) the destination parameter is undefined. But defaultPath is still a string. Is this a redux-thunk bug?

Comment: @Radio- I filled in more detail, but I also changed the title of the question, not realizing that would create a new note. See result at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43895229/redux-dispatchtoprops-dispatch-loses-context-and-arguments-when-getting-to-act

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, I did not plan on creating a duplicate post. What I did was expand a prior post, and give it a more accurate title. But it seems that since there were answers to the prior post, it left both. Is that the expected behavior, and how could I have avoided that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that redux is not happy with not plan javascript object. As shown above, when I tried to dispatch an actionCreator which had a bound function call as a parameter, it was missing when the actionCreator was created.

I also tried to create a reducer that placed a function handle (bound function) into the store, and it was not stored, and the prior value was removed (a placeholder).

I am puzzled by what @Radio- is saying, since what I am seeing is that redux does not like things that are not plain javascript objects (either as parameters to the dispatch call, or as values from the reducer to be placed in the store).

Comment: Neither the store nor the dispatcher strips functions from objects. It's not recommended to store function references in the store state, but you're not prevented from doing so. Are you storing the result of a function call instead of a function pointer? It's the only thing that comes to mind without seeing the code in question.

Comment: @Radio- If you don't mind, look at the updated question above, and I think you will see what I am seeing, the bound function being passed to dispatch() is getting stripped. I also see the same thing when I try to use a reducer to put a bound function in the store. The only reason I was doing this ugly thing was to get around a limitation with redux-form, which provides change() as a bound function local to the component, and I wanted it available globally.

Comment: It's <not available> because the JavaScript engine doesn't keep the name around because there isn't a reference to storeAct anywhere in the inner function. If you did reference it somewhere, then the engine would keep the name available, and it might be something different.

Answer (score 0):

The code which invokes `pickFolder` (i.e. `Act.pickFolder(Act.setSourcePath, defaultPath)`) has nothing to do with `redux-thunk` at all. It will be evaluated before `redux-thunk` will come into play, because of the way `redux-thunk` works.

`redux-thunk` checks if dispatched value was a function and if it was, `redux-thunk` invokes it with `dispatch`, `getState` and `extraArgument` params. Please [check its source code](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk/blob/master/src/index.js#L4), it's really tiny and simple.

Basically it means exactly what Radio said: if it's undefined in pickFolder that's because it was undefined in the caller. Also I don't see any usages of `destination` in your `pickFolder`, so maybe check for the typos.

Comment: I expanded the details, you can see it at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43895229/redux-dispatchtoprops-dispatch-loses-context-and-arguments-when-getting-to-act